# tf.exe "you are not authorized to access", is not accepting my login parameter

Tags: command-line, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to solve this problem since a long time, every execution I perform on TF.exe command, is throwing TF30063 exception, when i'm the admin and the only user of my TFS.

Problem: Try to execute this in a clean machine, without any visual studio user logged in on visual studio, **IMPORTANT: also remove your user from windows credentials**.

```
tf.exe workspaces /computer:mycomputer
```

[image]

This modal pops up prompting for credentials, but I need something to be run in a command window without user interference, so checking help I see that you could send `/login:user,password`

Then, again let's try with that in the command:

```
tf.exe workspaces /computer:mycomputer /login:myuser@outlook.com,MyPassword
```

And now, I get the following exception:

```
TF30063: You are not authorized to access xxx
```

BUT, and for the last, if I login on that popup (which I don't want to do because it will be a remote build service) suddenly all commands works fine.

What is the point of having /login command if is not useful here? is there a way to perform this login without prompt?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I also tried to add in the Windows Certificates, using cmdkey.exe, the acount that is trying to log in, but this was not also useful.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using VSTS, not on-premises TFS. Usually **/login** option can be used on on-premises TFS, we use the **/login** option to specify the Team Foundation Server user account to run a command.

If you want to use on VSTS, you need to get a OAuth token, and specify `/loginType:OAuth`. The command line is:

```
tf workspaces /collection:https://xxxx.visualstudio.com /loginType:OAuth /login:.,[OAuth token]
```

Add a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Indeed, i´m using VSTS, I was not aware of this difference, but I see your point, probably the command that I ran will work if I have a on-premise TFS. But anyway, do you know how could I authenticate to my VSTS by command line?

Comment: You need to get a OAuth token by following [this article](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-auth-samples/tree/master/OAuthWebSample), specify `/loginType:OAuth` and use the OAuth token as password in the command line: `tf workspaces /collection:https://xxxx.visualstudio.com /loginType:OAuth /login:.,**** `

Comment: Or set up a PAT if you don’t want to use OAuth.

Comment: This looks promising, I will give a try and get back to mark as answer if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Yogurtu It works on my side, let us know whether it works for you.

Comment: @Yogurtu Have you tired this command? Is it working on your side?

Comment: Hi friend, so at last I was able to check this command (sorry for the delay) unfortunatelly, without success, It was a progress to understand that basic authentication (user,password) is not an option, so I wen to my security settings, and I can see I can generate PAT token, when I try to use this token with your example, throws same error, is your answer ment to be for Oauth2 only? what can I use for PAT?

Comment: PAT doesn't work from my test, you have to use a OAuth token.

Comment: So I created a OAuth token, I got the token, I can execute stuff in the TfsApi (Get projects), but still, TF.exe is not working while assigning a valid (not expired) token... what could be wrong? Did you made this work or is assumptions that should work?

Comment: Yes, it works on my side. Please check my screenshot.

Comment: The instructions for getting an OAuth token (in the OAuthWebSample) require deploying an app to Azure Web Apps.  Isn't there a better way to get a token?  I find it unreasonable to have to deploy a *web app* to *public hosting* to get the token I need to authenticate a *command-line* tool to pull from source control (as well as quite impractical given the approvals I'd need do it).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been very long since this thread is opened but I recently experienced the same issue and resolved it by following the below steps. This maybe helpful for people who will get stuck with this issue in future...

Yes, I have faced the same issue and was able to resolve the issue finally :)

The problem is that tf.exe command with the switch "/login:username,password"  works as expected with the onprem versions, however you have to use OAuth for saas version. Please find the below example command for saas version for your reference.

tf workspaces /collection:https://dev.azure.com/OrganizationName /loginType:OAuth /login:.,OAuthtoken

To generate the OAuth token you should be using the following article as a reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops

Hope this helps someone at some point of time :)