How to call tf.exe in C# so it prompts for login?
This is a problem that's been a thorn in our side for years. I currently have a .bat file which gets latest on a requested folder. The 'tf get' command in this .bat will automatically prompt for login credentials if necessary. This usually happens after a password reset.
The problem is it's not reliable. Often times we're not able to use this .bat file because it fails to ask for credentials, instead giving a TF30063 error saying the user is not authorized to access the project. We've scoured stackoverflow and Microsoft support forums for years to find a solution, with no success.
So I've written a C# wpf application to replace the .bat file. The Dea being to attack the issue from a different angle. It works fine, except it never prompts for login credentials, even when the .bat file does. It only ever throws the TF30063 error. My current workaround is to run the .bat file just to trigger the login. Afterward both the .bat and C# program can call 'tf get' without error.
So what could be causing the C# version to fail displaying a prompt when other options succeed,and how can that failure be resolved?
The C# code in question:
Process process = new Process
{
  StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
  {
    Filename = "{Exe Path}\TF.exe",
    Arguments = "get {Folder Path} /recursive /prompt /login:PATtoken",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
  },
};

process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += HandleProcessOutput;
process.ErrorDataReceived += HandleProcessErrorOutput;
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

And this is the .bat call. (Using a Visual Studio Dev command prompt)
tf get {Path To Folder} /recursive /login:PATtoken

Things we've tried to invalidate or overwrite our current credentials:

Log out and reenter credentials in Visual Studio (No effect)
Delete all windows credentials listed in Credential Manager (No effect)
Disconnect and reconnect to the project in Visual Studio Team Explorer (No effect)
Get latest via Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio (This always gets latest, but doesn't trigger the login prompt)
Use the right-click context menu granted from the TFS Shell Extension (Acts same as the .bat file, where it doesn't always trigger the login prompt but will get latest, etc. if the prompt is triggered elsewhere)
Log out and log back in on the project page
Several suggestions said to try logging out and log back in to the project page via Visual Studio's inbuilt web browser (This appears to no longer be supported)
Delete VssApp credentials in the registry (I've not done this as it would require an IT request, and wouldn't be a valid solution regardless)

As far as C# specific attempts, a lot of what's in the C# snippet is what's been tried. Highlights being the inclusion of /prompt and /login:PATtoken to the arguments and setting EnableRaisingEvents to true in the hopes one of them might help. (Interestingly, the TF30063 error message gets displayed twice when there's no /login argument. Otherwise it only displays once.) I understand that capturing the error message is supposed to keep the login prompt from displaying. However, it still won't display with those lines set to false, and UseShellExecute set to true. In that case, a shell window displays with the error text and nothing else.
I originally wanted to use the web api since that's the most current way to get latest on project files. (I believe it is anyway. Digging through this topic has revealed a decade of increasingly out of date info) The hope was to not rely on TF.exe at all. I could never figure out how to connect to our project though, and ended up returning to the exe.

The following may be of interest: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-run-tfexe-with-the-login-switch/877704

Is this for an on-premise Azure DevOps Server and if so what version? Or is this for the cloud Azure DevOps Services? You are using tf get so the repo is TFVC, is that correct? The current working directory should be the local workspace folder or a sub-folder. tf will try to determine and use the login from the workspace but that will fail if the working directory is not part of a workspace.

@JonathanDodds This is for the Azure cloud service, and yes. We're using TFVC.  Both methods of using tf get are being pointed to workspace folders, which is the {Folder Path} in the above code examples.  I believe the issue is because the command is trying to use outdated login credentials, but haven't been able to confirm that theory.  I'm not sure how it decides to display the login prompt or not.

@user246821 I'd seen the OAuth token idea before.  I'll mess around with it again. See if anything works out this time.

You can try to use the Process.Start() method to run the command prompt and execute the tf.exe command Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c tf.exe login");. I did some search and investigation, for Azure DevOps service, it's suggested to use OAuth for login. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614268/tf-exe-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-is-not-accepting-my-login-parameter.
